# How to exclude sitemap.xml from caching in swift performance plugin?

Tags: web, caching, sitemap

I want to know how to exclude sitemap from being caching in swift performance plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude sitemap from being caching follow this process. open swift performance, then click on caching - exclude site url section add your sitemap url. i.e. https://example.com/sitemap.xml. use your website name in example.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is working. I have been struggling with this sitemap caching issue for over 1 month.